# Failing to load OS .gz files into QGIS 3.16 using OS Translator II

Tags: qgis, postgis, qgis-plugins, ordnance-survey, os-mastermap

I'm new to QGIS and not strong on writing scripts or code. That said I've installed QGIS 3.16, PostGIS 3.1.0,  PostgreSQL 13 and also OS Translator 2 and followed the configuration guidance at https://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/projects/ostranslator-ii/ to add the symbol files, fonts and SVG paths which look like this ..[image: SVG paths]

I've created a connection to the database ...

[image: database connection]

The OS  Translator 2, is configured as follows

[image: OS Translator config]

When I press Ok to run the translator I get the following error message:

[image: OS Translator 2 error message]

I suspect I'm making a / some simple mistake(s).

Comment: Please add the error messages as text, not picture.

Answer (score 1):

Your database doesn't have postgis installed.

```
create extension postgis;
```

should fix it (or you can use a GUI like PGAdmin4 to add it).